# android: how to set overflow menu in aciton bar

Tags: android, overflow, android-actionbar

i am trying to customize my action bar, and willing to put some actions into the overflow, so i used `showAsAction="ifRoom"` in my menu xml file.

the problem is, my action bar doesn't want to take more than 2 action(is this normal?), and don't show the overflow menu which is supposed to be included if there's not enough space in screen.

any hints or solutions please?

Thank you

Comment: Is this on a device with a menu button?

Comment: @JulianFondren i guess it is, yes. i am actually using the classic AVM.

Answer (score 2):

To get it to show on an Android 4.0 device (not 100% sure it will work on older devices, but it may with the compatability package) I also had to add `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in either the `<application />` or `<activity />` section depending on the usage you want.

Also, `showAsAction="ifRoom"` will most likely not show them... try using `showAsAction="always"` to get it working at least and then try playing with them!

Hope this helps....